# How we can scroll recyclerview at specific position in android

Tags: android

i want to scroll recycler view after data created at specific position. and the item should be displayed in Center of Activity or Fragment. But not able to scroll at specific position. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
```